# compound literal and pass by reference in C++ with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

> In C++, a compound literal designates a temporary object, which only
>   lives until the end of its full-expression. As a result, well-defined
>   C code that takes the address of a subobject of a compound literal can
>   be undefined in C++.
>   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html

Does this apply to pass-by-reference, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The undefined behaviour comes from trying to access the object after its destruction, whether that's done via a dangling pointer or a dangling reference.